# Can we represent a parabola or data on the parabolic curve as a sum of two exponential functions?

Tags: exponential-function

I am just wondering, is it possible to represent a parabola or data on the parabolic curve as a sum of two exponential functions?

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: There might be a way with Taylor series, but it would be very complex and absolutely not worth it.

Comment: Are you tempted to assimilate the curve of $y=\cosh(x):=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ with a parabola ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, by definition, [parabolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) are a specific conic section, you can represent all of them using quadratic equations, but there's no way to precisely represent them using a sum of $2$ exponential functions. However, for a "parabolic curve", if you mean something which is similar to a parabola, how about double the hyperbolic cosine function of $\cosh(x)$, i.e., $f(x) = e^x + e^{-x}$? It's the sum of $2$ exponential functions. As shown in [cosh function graph](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=YahG9ivR&id=A2EF6D77A98A97E3DA887C11D361C6080D4DB11A&thid=OIP.YahG9ivRIb2evxK7ln80PwAAAA&mediaurl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.ccp14.ac.uk%2fccp%2fweb-mirrors%2fdplot%2ffunctions%2fcosh.png&exph=399&expw=463&q=cosh+function+graph&simid=608009682376197520&selectedIndex=1&ajaxhist=0), its graph looks much like a concave up parabola with an axis of symmetry at $x = 0$, plus a minimum of $1$ at $x = 0$ for $\cosh(x)$, and a minimum of $2$ for $f(x)$.